# "UIRequiresFullScreen" (info.plist)

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, fullscreen, multitasking

I'm building an app that can't appear in Slide Over or Split View. So, I added the new key "UIRequiresFullScreen" in my info.plist.

It works fine, but something weird happens when I try to access `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` in `viewWillTransitionToSize` method:

**UIRequiresFullScreen => NO**

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    print(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    // iPad Pro Simulator, transitioning between Portrait to Landscape
    // prints: (0.0, 0.0, 1366.0, 1024.0)
}
```

**UIRequiresFullScreen => YES**

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    print(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    // iPad Pro Simulator, transitioning between Portrait to Landscape
    // prints: (0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1366.0)
}
```

What's happening??

**OBS:** I'm using iOS 9 SDK, supporting all orientations, using Size Class and a launch storyboard, so my last hope is this `UIRequiresFullScreen` key.

Comment: You might have to lock the orientation when you set UIRequiresFullScreen to YES.

Comment: @GlennRay I need to support all orientations. Furthermore, if I lock the orientation I wouldn't need to set `UIRequiresFullScreen` to `YES` to opt out to participate in Slide Over and Split View.

Comment: According to Apple documentation, you can disable Slide Over and Split View in Settings > General > Multitasking at the same time you set UIRequiresFullScreen to YES.  I'm not sure if that's a user setting or a project setting.  Have you tried that?

Comment: It seems "disable Slide Over and Split View in Settings > General > Multitasking" is set by the user on the device (and, I suppose, the simulator).

Comment: Try printing out what the system thinks the device orientation is for each case.  You could use `UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;' and then check if either '(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))' or  '(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))' is TRUE.